# How to make min() choose two numbers

Tags: javascript, list, variables, numbers, min

I would like min() to choose the two smallest numbers in a list, is this possible and how should I do it?

Comment: This is a homework?? Is better that you work, searching on google...

Comment: No, this isn't a homework. I'm doing something that dosen't have with school to do.

Comment: Please expand your question. What have you tried?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/tutorials/programming-basics and 
http://www.learnjquery.org/tutorials/
Study...

Comment: Err Math.min() does exactly that; 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_min.asp (read the full page and not just the first line of the manual)

Comment: Guys, you haven't got this right. I wan't the TWO LOWEST numbers, not the lowest. Trying to find it my self but I thought this maybe would be faster but really it dosen't seem so.

Comment: yeah, i think there was confusion over that, math.min does allow many inputs, but only one output...

Answer (score 4):

actually, Math.min only gives you the single smallest of a list, so you need to simply sort them all and grab the quantity you need:

```
list = [7,4,5,4,2,23,4,6,4,6];
smalls = list.sort(function(a,b){return a-b}).slice(0,2);
alert(smalls); // shows "2, 4"
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you, I were close to discovering it by my self, but you made the search a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is a little inefficient as it takes up O(n log n) time. You could do the same thing with a single pass. Just keep to variables that are initialized to empty (or negative inifinity) or something.

For every element encountered, check against the two variables and update accordingly.

It is pretty simple but it takes up only linear time O(n).

Answer (score -1):

Search for a documentation on "Math" (it is a javascript object with many useful math related functions and variables).

[Hint.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_math.asp)

Comment: This should probably be a comment. Also, try to avoid w3schools; they're not really known for [accuracy and showing good practices](http://www.w3fools.com/).